# Como renderizar elemento em react com map?

Tags: array, react, map

Como renderizar elemento em react com `map`?

Não entendi porque não consigo renderizar os itens da lista.

```
import React from 'react' import Header from './Header'

    const Duvidas = () => {
    
    const accordionContent = [  {id: 1,
      question: 'Question 1', 
      content:' It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. '
      },
    
      {id: 2,
      question: 'Question 2', 
      content: 'There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which'
      },
    
      {id: 3,
      question: 'Question 3', 
      content: 'The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32'
      },
    
      {id: 4,
      question: 'Question 4', 
      content: 'Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search.'
      } 
    ];
    return ( <>
    
      <div className='container-faq'>
    
          <div className='wrapper'>
    
            <div className='accordion'>
                {accordionContent.map((data) => {
                  <div className='item' key={data.id}>
    
                    <div className='title'> 
                      <h2>{data.question}</h2>
                      <span><img src="../img/angulo-para-baixo.png"/></span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                      {data.content}
                    </div>
                  
                  </div>
                  })
                }
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </>
      )
    }
```

Já editei as perguntas, mas não me deixam publicar mais.
Editando novamente.

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta para ficar compreensível. A pergunta tem texto duplicado, código não formatado e um parágrafo de pergunta fechada (sic).

Comment: @CésarRodriguez corrigi, se puder ajudar, ficarei grata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o teu map de `accordionContent` não tá retornando nada, por isso não renderiza.

```
.....
{accordionContent.map((data) => {
     return <div className='item' key={data.id}>
....
```

isso vai resolver

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigada! Achei que a arrow function já ia retornar automático.

Comment: Então, ele até retorna automático mas apenas quando não há as chaves que delimitam a função interna (e quando é apenas uma instrução de linha única). Por exemplo, assim funcionaria:

accordionContent.map((data) => <div className='item' key={data.id}>)